# Geographical Data Visualization in a Web Application

Tags: dictionary, charts, data-visualization

I've got a request to implement a visualization service for geographical related data.

I have a list of **Italian ZIP Codes** (they are called CAP in Italian). I've already found a table which maps these ZIP codes to **geographical coordinates (lat/long)**.

So, the data I have to visualize as map is structured the following way:

```
ZIPcode Latitude Longitude RequestCount
------- -------- --------- ------------
```

Is there an easy way (using a web service or implementing it myself using a component - preferably in .NET) for **creating a map chart similar to the image i inserted below**? It needn't to be that pretty and **not necessarily geo-political**.

I just need a indicator for every point which shows a **smaller or bigger circle and next to it the value** of RequestCount. I think this could be done either using the coordinates or, if there is some service which maps the Italian ZIP codes, using the ZIP code.

*Thank you in advance!*

[alt text http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/3814/carsalesuh6.png](http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/3814/carsalesuh6.png)

Comment: You can also consider [Nevron Chart for .NET](https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-diagram-gallery-maps-general-maps.aspx). Has plenty of options for customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=80125&country=IT) offers a data set and open source libraries for geo mapping

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [.net Charting](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/map_charts.aspx) and [Chart FX Maps](http://www.softwarefx.com/Extensions/featuresMaps.aspx) (I've never used these before).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe...

Use the Google Map API.  You can't draw circle overlays, but you can draw polygons.  Here's the API for drawing polygons.   An 8-sided polygon already looks pretty circle like.  You could experiment with more sides to see how that looks.

Here's the API reference for the Google GPolygon class:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GPolygon

Answer (score 2):

I've used MapServer for many projects and it works well and is very flexible. Haven't tried the .NET bindings though:

http://www.paolocorti.net/2006/09/20/mapserver-tutorial-for-c-mapscript-asp-net/

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Fusion Maps](http://www.fusioncharts.com/maps/) for things like this.  It is flash based with a javascript API.  You can easily feed it either a static XML file to start, but I've also built various webservices to give it dynamic capabilities.  There are many options to change the look and feel of the map as well.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at Mapv - a library of geography visualization

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Niol6.jpg)